# Python: How to get a table row by a string inside it via BeatifullSoup?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
<tr class="list even">
    <td class="list">5</td>
    <td class="list"><s>BI</s>→MU</td>
    <td class="list"><s>TEACHER</s>→TEACHER</td>
    <td class="list">Hello I am a Text</td>
    <td class="list">5b</td>
    <td class="list">BI3</td></tr>
```

This is one of the table rows. There are some with one row as an inline header, but idc for them.

So, I want to only get the rows that contains the string "8f" but not only the `td`, the whole `tr`
In case there are multiple rows containing the string it should give me a list from them

```
for row in soup.find_all('tr', class_='list even'):
    if '5b' in row.text:
        print(row)
        for cell in row.find_all('td'):
            if "5b" not in cell.text:
                print(cell.text)

for row in soup.find_all('tr', class_='list odd'):
    if '5b' in row.text:
        for cell in row.find_all('td'):
            if "5b" not in cell.text:
                print(cell.text)
```

I have this now, but it adds a newline before the last table field:
https://haste.thevillage.chat/foguvakixa.py

```
if "5b" not in cell.text:
```

This is because if i request the data for 5d i dont need to know again that its 5d. So this just filters the class itselfs out

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Nothing, i havent found anything on how to do this

Answer (score 2):

You could use pandas read_html to grab table then filter on klasse column

```
import pandas as pd

def get_lectures_two(df, klasse):    
    new_df = df[df['(Klasse(n))'] == klasse]
    return new_df

def get_df(url):
    df = pd.read_html(url)[0]
    df = df[~df['Stunde'].str.contains("LEHRER")]
    return df

df = get_df('https://niwla23.gitlab.io/download/vertreterdemo.html')
print(get_lectures_two(df, '5b'))
```

---

With bs4 4.7.1 + you can use :contains and :has, along with the appropriate column index via nth-of-type to target the appropriate rows (I use pandas here just to quickly generate a nice tabular output for viewing.... you already have the lists of lists from bs4 and could use csv to write for example)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd

def get_lectures(klasse):
    rows = []
    for row in soup.select(f'.mon_list tr:has(td:nth-of-type(5):contains("{klasse}"))'):
        rows.append([td.text.replace('\xa0','') for td in row.select('td')])
    return rows

r = requests.get('https://niwla23.gitlab.io/download/vertreterdemo.html')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
headers = [th.text for th in soup.select('th.list')]
klasse = '5b'

df = pd.DataFrame(get_lectures(klasse), columns = headers)
print(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code.fetch the row text and check if its having `5b`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
res=requests.get("http://niwla23.gitlab.io/download/vertreterdemo.html")
soup=BeautifulSoup(res.text,'lxml')

for row in soup.find_all('tr', class_='list even'):
    if '5b' in row.text:
        print(row.text)
```

Comment: Can you share your url and expected output as well?

Comment: Its on our school server, heres a copy with blacked names:
http://niwla23.gitlab.io/download/vertreterdemo.html
So I want to have all the rows between one header and a the next header.
So the plan for one class.

Comment: @Niwla23 : what you expect from that link?

Comment: @Niwla23 : Check above answer worked for you? Change 5b to 8f in your code.Let me know how it goes?

Comment: bs4.FeatureNotFound: Couldn't find a tree builder with the features you requested: lxml. Do you need to install a parser library? @KunduK

Comment: change to  'lxml' to 'htmt.parser'

Comment: for some reason it always breaks the line for the last thing (room). So it makes a newline. How can I fix that?

Comment: Could you please post text and your expected text here?

Comment: @Niwla23 : When I print on my pc the data is coming like this : `1
MU→DE
LEHER24→LEHER22
 
5b
MU3→B2.02


5
BI→MU
LEHRER1→LEHER24
 
5b
BI3`

Comment: https://haste.thevillage.chat/omuvefimif.py
I changed a code a bit, waht if you execute that? It filters unneccasary things out and also parses the other rows @KunduK

Comment: @Niwla23 : If you could update your url in your original post and provide clean output what you are after from webpage with example data that would be great.I confuse ATM about your expected output.I thought you might need rows data which contains `5b` and I produce that.If Not please update the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can find all of tds that contains `5b` using only BS like that:

```py
tds_5b = soup.find_all('td', class_='list', text='5b')
```

and then iterate through them to find a parent `tr` element for each of them:

```py
out = set()
for row in tds_5b :
    out.add(row.find_parent('tr'))
```